# shopping list app: using checkboxes to cross off items

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a shopping list application via javascript/jquery and i'm having trouble using checkboxes to cross off items on the list. i'm getting close though. when a box is checked, all of the items in the list become crossed off, and also the text in the main text-input at the top of the application has the strikethrough quality as well. checking one of the boxes should only strikethrough the corresponding text next to it.

here is my javascript for this particular function:

```
$('#shopping-list').on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
    var input = $(this).parent().siblings('input[type=text]');
    $('input').css('textDecoration','line-through');

});
```

also here is a link for the current version of the application:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91499081/ShoppingList/shoppingList.html

Comment: Post your HTML markup directly in the question rather than linking to it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake - made it many times myself.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P2wA8/)

You correctly identify the specific input tag that you want to underline, and you assign that tag to a variable.

But in your next jQuery line, you put the variable name as a string, which tells jQuery that you want to get all elements of that type. Since "input" is a valid type of elements, all input elements are modified.

Therefore, change:

```
$('input').css('textDecoration','line-through');
```

To:

```
$(input).css('textDecoration','line-through');
```

I would also recommend choosing a different var name. Had you used a different var name, such as "myInput", you may have found the solution yourself.

---

Per your comment question:

To check/uncheck the text field:

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/P2wA8/1/)

```
$('#shopping-list').on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
    var input = $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]');
    if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $(input).css('textDecoration','line-through');
    }else{
        $(input).css('textDecoration','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, that works! any suggestions for how i could remove the strikethrough if the box is thereafter unchecked? because currently the strikethrough remains even when the box gets unchecked.

Comment: @user2976607 See update to my answer. Please remember to select a correct answer when satisfied.

Comment: duh that was easy, i shoulda figured that one out. thanks! and correct answer selected!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
$('#shopping-list').on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(evt){
    var checkbox = $(evt.target),
        textInput = checkbox.next('input[type=text]');

    textInput.css('text-decoration', checkbox.is(':checked') ? 'line-through' : 'none');
});
```

You were going up to the parent, then selecting all the input children that were text inputs, instead of only the text right after the check box.

Checking if the checkbox is checked will allow the line through to toggle as the user keeps clicking the box.

Comment: when i tried this code nothing is getting the strikethrough styling anymore

Comment: Change `textInput = checkbox.next('input[type=text]');` to `textInput = checkbox.parent().next('input[type=text]');`